# Do I need to create a new database for copies of the same form?

Tags: php, database, forms, mysqli

Here goes a very basic question.
Here is my stroll in trying to create a form for work:

I created the HTML form. Added some JavaScript to make it do some things I needed. Stylized it with CSS, wrote PHP code and created a Database (I had no idea of how to do it at first) for the entered data to be saved.
I didn't know how to do any of that, but in the past two weeks I've managed to make it exactly the way I needed, and I'm very pleased with myself. After a lot of work, the form perfectly sends the data to the database and displays it in the page after you hit submit, and also looks really good too.

The thing is... this that I am creating is an Activities Bank for us to use here at work (I teach English) and the page (base) I have created is only ONE of MANY that are needed in this data bank. Let me explain... Let's say the page I've created is the post and display of, say, Book3 Chapter1 Activities, and I need to have many other pages (which will be exact copies of this one).

My question is... will I have to create (actually, it's copy and paste) new databases/tables manually (which will be more than one hundred of them) or there is a way to automatize this process?

I mean, all the pages will share the same variables and the same form... the only different thing will be the title and the entered data, of course.

Will I have to create a database for each page? Or a new table for each page in the same database?

If you still don't understand what I need, here is how this is supposed to be:
Book1 has 40 chapters, so, 40 copies of the same form (which already works fine);
PLUS
Book2 that has 40 more chapters, etc.

Thanks in advance for any clarification.
Sorry if this is such a basic question, but if it isn't, if otherwise, what I wanna do is very complicated, I don't mind that I don't know much about all this and I will take the challenge, like I have, when I was making this form from scratch, without ever hearing about "databases". Any words of help are appreciated.

Comment: You only use 1 database with many table with many records on it. What do I understand in your situation you can have a table name `Books` with columns `id` , `name` and extend it's metadata to table name `Chapters` and learn how to join tables. My suggestion you need to read [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/sql-for-beginners/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't how databases or tables work. You should be creating a new *row* in one or more tables for each form submission. You should almost never be dynamically creating tables, and even less often databases.

It sounds like you want a `books` table, and a `chapters` table. Each row in the books table will have many rows in the chapters table "pointing" to it via foreign keys.

Comment: I don't think you guys understand. I am doing everything in a database named "activitybank" and a table with the name "book3chapter1". The php page I have successfully created is a model that corresponds to the activities of Book3Chapter1, and has about 20 variables. Like I said before, all the other hundreds of php pages I'll create (one for each chapter of each book) will be exact copies of this model (except for the code regarding the tables it sends its information too, which, I think, will have to be one php page to one table.

Comment: This is my very doubt: Should I create all the other tables (all the other chapters of the books) manually or I'll need only one table, since all the php pages have the same variables? But then, when someone goes to, say, page book2chapter1.php and enters data, it will mix up with the data from book3chapter1.php, with the data from book3chapter2.php, and all the other ones. Since I use a code that displays the entered data in the same page of the form, everypage would be a crazy mix of all the data entered in that table ever, and what I want is that each page shows only ITS OWN activities.

Comment: I mean, how do the posts in forums work? I mean, I submit data (my post) into a table that ONLY HAS the data from that page or it sends my post to a table where all the other posts in that forum are stored? If so, how do they get each page to only echo the posts that were submitted in that very page? Do you guys understand my point now?

Comment: @jcodi A simple forum will have **one table** called `posts`. It will contain **one row** for each post. It's up to the page to query the correct row out of each table, and display the results. The problem here is that you've named your table too specifically. You should have a table called `books`, with an `id` column and a `name` column. In that table there should be a row containing `id: 1; name: book 3`. In a **different** table called `chapters`, you would have a row for chapter three, pointing to book 1.

Comment: This is getting very off-topic for Stack Overflow. You need to read a tutorial on how to build a proper database schema, you are doing it very backwards right now. You then need to read a PHP tutorial, because you're doing that part backwards too. You should not have one PHP age per book. You should have one PHP page for *all* books, which is passed query string parameters; something like `books.php?book=3&chapter=1`.

Comment: **Like I said before, all the other hundreds of php pages I'll create (one for each chapter of each book) will be exact copies of this model (except for the code regarding the tables it sends its information too, which, I think, will have to be one php page to one table. – jcodi 8 hours ago** This is the most backwards thing of all. This isn't how programming is supposed to work. **DO NOT DO THIS**. You should have **one model** which is passed the name of its table when instantiated!

Comment: Thank you, maegar! You said "You should have one PHP page for all books, which is passed query string parameters; something like books.php?book=3&chapter=1", and "It's up to the page to query the correct row out of each table, and display the results." and I'd like to learn how to do that. Do you have a link? I don't know how to look for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case your case two tables.in total.
As you have already added one, you need another one, where the first one will contain the common data with a primary key column and the other table will keep the primary key of the first table and the data which occurs in multiple. Then later you needs to join (Sql join)rotatable to get your data.